# Having problems parallelizing

Tags: for-loop

I calculate a number of sums and I need to find the minimum of the sums. I'm able to do serially, but I'm having a hard time parallelizing it using mpi. serially, I calculate the specific sums and find the minimums as so:

```
for(i = 0; i < size; i++){
    for(j = 0; j < size; j++){
        for(k = 0; k < size; k+=gap){
            for(m = 0; m < size; m+=gap){
                c1 = calculation1(i,j,k,m);
                if(c1 > cutoff){
                    sum += calculation2(modifier1[k][m], modifier2[k][m]);
                }
            }
        }
        if(sum < min){
            min = sum;
        }
        sum = 0;
    }
}
```

This is what I currently have for the parallel version using mpi:

```
        MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
        MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numprocs);
        MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &myid);
                     .
                     .
                     .   
        x = (size)/numprocs;
        low = myid * x;
        high = low + x;

        for(i =low; i < high; i++){
            for(j = low; j < high; j++){
                for(k = low; k < high; k+=gap){
                    for(m = low; m < high; m+=gap){
                                        c1 = calculation1(i,j,k,m);
                        if(c1 > cutoff){
                            sum += calculation2(modifier1[k][m], modifier2[k][m]);
                        }      
                    }
                }

                MPI_Reduce(&sum, &result, 1, MPI_FLOAT, MPI_SUM, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
                sum = 0;
            }
        }   
    MPI_Reduce(&result, &minimum, 1, MPI_FLOAT, MPI_MIN, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    if( 0 == myid)
    printf("The  min is: %f", minimum);
    MPI_Finalize();
```

I've tried other variations, including not using the MPI_Reduce with the MPI_Min argument and just using my own method to get the minimum, however I never get the same answer as the serial version. Any insight to what my wrong-doing is here would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only split up the outer loop and keep the inner loops the same. If there's 4 processes then you want each process to do a quarter of the work, not "a quarter of a quarter of a quarter" of the work.

You should keep track of a local sum and a local minimum for each process separately, and only combine the sum and minimum from each process after all the work has been done. This means moving the first "MPI_Reduce()" out of the loop/s and put it where the second "MPI_Reduce()" is. It also means you still need to do "if(sum < min){ min = sum; }" to determine the process' local minimum.